# Varnish & Varnishncsa Logging Problems

Tags: logging, logstash, amazon-cloudfront, varnish

Just noticing some weird behaviour with varnishncsa logs, which I push into an ELK stack..

In order to maintain an accurate client IP address, I have the following in my varnish config:
```
    // Save original values
    set req.http.X-Varnish-Orig-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
    set req.http.X-Varnish-Orig-clientip = client.ip;

```
// Check / normalise forwarded for header for below C logic
if(req.http.CloudFront-Viewer-Country) {
    // Cloudfront request? Note: This header must be configured in CF settings
    // Remove right most IP address, it belongs to CF
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, ",.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", "");
}

// Remove all but the right most IP
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, ".*,\s", "");
```

ie. remove the cloudfront IP and leaves the correct client address(es).

However, I'm noticing that in logstash this is not what is happening.. the CloudFront IP is always coming through...

My varnishncsa log format is set to: logformat="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" \"%{X-Forwarded-Proto}i\""

heres an example log:

85.101.101.101, 54.240.145.45 - - [31/Oct/2016:14:55:53 +1100] "GET http://example.com/stuff/things&349394 HTTP/1.1" 200 65733 "https://example.com&ttl=30&unique_id=1" "Amazon CloudFront" "https"

As you can see the 54.240 is an AWS address ie. CloudFront... My grok for varnish logs is set to parse the x-forwarded-for and set the last IP as the client ip. Obviously, with CloudFront coming through as its not supposed to its throwing a spanner in the works for setting the proper client ip...

Any idea what is going wrong here? To me it seems varnishncsa is sending off its logging before the vcl_recv logic in my varnish config has a chance to run...? but that would make little sense. At what part in the execution of a request does the varnishncsa log come into play? I would have assumed the very last.....?

Comment: Well, you're testing `if(req.http.CloudFront-Viewer-Country) {` which is a header that CloudFront doesn't  add unless you specifically ask it to... is this header included in the incoming requests?

Comment: Yep, this header is definitely added. I've tested extensively and varnishncsa is logging the raw request before any logic in the varnish config is hitting it.

A little further digging, I've noticed as im running varnish 3.x, in later versions theres options for client and backend logging.. So it would appear this was intended behaviour, which has since been adjusted for.. It appears varnish v4.x & 5.x have flags to log either side of the client or backend request.

Unfortunately, upgrading from v3 is going to be a major task. A way to do this in v3 would be a godsend....